# Why was this bounty not rewarded?

Tags: support

Regarding this question: 
[How to build a 2N6027 PUT?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28864/how-to-build-a-2n6027-put) which was to rewarded with a +500 bounty.

From Kortuk's profile page I understand the bounty was rewarded to me:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/230/kortuk?tab=bounties

But I am under the impression that I never actually received that bounty. What is the reasoning behind not rewarding the bounty? Did I miss anything or am I misreading the information? Please help me understand the mechanics behind bounties being rewarded or not.

Comment: What are you looking for as far as an answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page shows a name that looks like the person whom garnered the bounty but it is actually whom last answered/edited the question.

You were the last to post an answer, it shows you there.

Comment: No reason to get mad at yourself, no worries. I'm just trying to understand the mechanics. Why does my name appear in the list on your profile if it was not awarded to me?

Comment: @jippie, updated.

Comment: Ah I see. Thnx for the effort Kortuk.

Comment: @jippie, sorry the answer did not include you being awarded 500 rep :(

Comment: Getting down voted by -1 on a random answer anywhere on SE, strangely feels much worse than not being awarded this one bounty. Don't worry, at least I understand the mechanics now.

Comment: @jippie, as has been the hot topic recently, dont take upvotes overly seriously, if someone give you constructive criticism take the time to improve if you want, otherwise ignore them.

Comment: How much reputation do I need to earn the privilege of "Free beer at the local pub"?

Comment: Depends on how local the pub is to other users whom value reputation, probably a lot, both reputation and driving. I will buy you a bear when you hit 1k and every 10dB after that.

Comment: :o) I start working on that right away!